# Instagram Search query to find an user by firstName and lastName

Tags: java, search, instagram

I am using instgarm java api to find the user by using first and last name.
in that api i have to use the first name and last name of a user to find

```
public UserFeed searchUser(String query, int count) throws InstagramException {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(query, "search query cannot be null.");

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put(QueryParam.SEARCH_QUERY, query);

        if(count > 0) {
            params.put(QueryParam.COUNT, String.valueOf(count));
        }

        UserFeed userFeed = createInstagramObject(Verbs.GET, UserFeed.class, Methods.USERS_SEARCH, params);

        return userFeed;
    }
```

in that api i have the above method. How would i construct a query to find an user based on first and last name.
when i pass any name means it returns lot of users i want the exact search using first and last name.
Any one can help me?